# access ResourceDictionary across different projects in solution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

How do I access a `ResourceDictionary` from different project in a solution?

My Solution file contains a few projects. One of these projects is named "Common" and contains a Resource called `SharedResource.xaml`.

`SharedResource.xaml` in Common:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                        mc:Ignorable="d">
        <ImageBrush x:Key="UserIcon" ImageSource="/Images\icon_user.png"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

This is how I tried to make the SharedResource Dictionary usable in one of my UserControls.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MasterDataManagement.View.DisplayMasterDataView"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="600" d:DataContext="{Binding DisplayMasterDataViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

    <UserControl.Resources> 
        <ResourceDictionary> <!-- ERROR Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.-->
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Resources/SharedResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
    <!-- Removed Content -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work and I'm not sure what I missed. The Code above causes this error message: Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

Any thoughts?

Notes:

- I can't put the ResourceDictionary into `App.xaml` because I create direct UserControl instances(something like `UserControl uc = new DisplayMasterDataView()` ).
- Only the App.xaml from the Project which is set as StartUp Project is "executed". My solution consists out of one MainProject (which is set as StartUp Project) and a few other projects which are used as modules in the MainProject. Now, I need to use this modules in my MainProject which is done like this:

  UserControl uc = new DisplayMasterDataView();

My point is that creating an instance of an UserControl from a different project does not execute the `App.xaml` in the project which consist the UserControl. Therefore I have to use `<UserControl.Resources> </UserControl.Resources>` to define my resources.
I just mentioned this because the most sample projects use the `App.xaml` to define Resources.

Comment: Posted XAML is complete? Because i suspect you have defined some resources below resource dictionary for which you haven't set `x:Key`. Or may be in your ResourceDictionary there is another element except Image for which you haven't set key value.

Comment: The SharedResource.xaml is complete, it contains only one item with the x:Key UserIcon.

Comment: And what about `UserControl.Resources`?

Comment: you're right! Thanks for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

> Each dictionary entry must have an associated key...

Surely that error is just telling you that you need to add a key to your `ResourceDictionary` using the `x:Key` notation... in this case, the 'dictionary entry' is your `ResourceDictionary` and the 'associated key' is whatever you call it to reference it later, in my example below, '`CommonResourceDictionary`':

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="CommonResourceDictionary">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary 
Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Resources/SharedResources.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

My WinView project contains a file called ViewResources.xaml in which I place all the resources needed by the controls in that project. It also links in other xaml files in the same project:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MainTabControlStyle.xaml" />        
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- ==================== Data Templates ==================== -->

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNameSpace:MyViewModel}">
        <controls:MyUserControl MyProperty="{Binding ...etc...}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

My main project then references this in App.xaml:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- Main Theme -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPF.Themes;component/BureauBlue/Theme.xaml" />

            <!-- Global Resources for Views -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject.WinView;component/ViewResources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject.WinUI;component/HelpResources.xaml" />

        ... and so on and so forth ...

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

I don't see how this would stop you from creating UserControls directly.

Comment: creating UserControls directly from another project in the solution file is a problem, updated my post with short explanation. But this was only meant as side note, this is not the problem itself. The problem is the error message: Each dictionary entry must have an associated key

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the solution, thanks you for pointing me into the right direction **Rohit Vats**!

**Not Working**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <gridView:RadContextMenuXamlHolder x:Key="ContextMenuHolder">
        <telerik:RadContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=UIElement.Column.DataControl.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" InheritDataContext="False"
                                StaysOpen="True" x:Name="CellCellContextMenu" Placement="Bottom" Loaded="ContextMenu_OnLoaded">
            <telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="ColumnsMenuEntry" Header="Choose Columns:" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu.UIElement.Column.DataControl.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpenOnClick="True">
                <telerik:RadMenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </telerik:RadMenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Show all columns" Click="RadMenuItem_ShowAllColumns_OnClick"/>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Hide all columns" Click="RadMenuItem_HideAllColumns_OnClick"/>
        </telerik:RadContextMenu>
    </gridView:RadContextMenuXamlHolder>

    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell">
        <Setter Property="telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Path=CellContextMenu, Source={StaticResource ContextMenuHolder}}"/>
    </Style>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/SharedResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**Working**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <gridView:RadContextMenuXamlHolder x:Key="ContextMenuHolder">
            <telerik:RadContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=UIElement.Column.DataControl.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" InheritDataContext="False"
                                StaysOpen="True" x:Name="CellCellContextMenu" Placement="Bottom" Loaded="ContextMenu_OnLoaded">
                <telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="ColumnsMenuEntry" Header="Choose Columns:" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Menu.UIElement.Column.DataControl.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpenOnClick="True">
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadMenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Show all columns" Click="RadMenuItem_ShowAllColumns_OnClick"/>
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Hide all columns" Click="RadMenuItem_HideAllColumns_OnClick"/>
            </telerik:RadContextMenu>
        </gridView:RadContextMenuXamlHolder>

        <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell">
            <Setter Property="telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Path=CellContextMenu, Source={StaticResource ContextMenuHolder}}"/>
        </Style>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/SharedResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

the trick was to move all resources into the  `<ResourceDictionary> </ResourceDictionary>` tag.

Comment: I was sure that it has to be somewhere else. :)

Comment: anyway your comment was really helpful to me